# Bootstrap div position with display change

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

Hi everyone (please excuse me first because I'm french),

I have a page with short navbar (2 options) and manage several divs that I display or hide depending on the actions. However, my divs no longer position themselves in the right place when I re-display them. I tried so many possibilities that I got lost and it's my first post .. so please be nice :')

-I can't use embed images cause I'm new-

[The "home page" without any action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBG7p.jpg)

[When I click on any month, my div is on the right, as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZFFq.jpg)

[When I click on the navbar (Regroupement par mois), we can already see that the red div is placed below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmxZ8.jpg)

[Then, the result when I click again on a month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaaGB.jpg)

To summarize, when I click on the navigation bar (blue links), my div is placed below the first one (4th image), instead of remaining to the right as at the beginning (before clicking on the navbar, 2nd image)

**{I'm using Angular 10, Bootstrap 5.0.2 and Firefox}**

Here's an excerpt of my code:

The HTML part

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" (click)="openListDiv('listMonths')">
        Regroupement par mois
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" (click)="openListDiv('listCities')">
        Regroupement par ville
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="listMonths" class="row">
  <div id="colListMonth" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <b> <span class="pull-right"> Nombre d'images </span></b>
      </a>
      <a *ngFor="let month of months; let i = index" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" (click)="getCountByDay(month[0])">
        {{month[1]}} {{month[2]}} <span class="badge badge-pill bg-secondary pull-right">{{countByMonth[i]}}</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="colListDates" class="col-md-4">
    <div id="listDates" class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <b>Dates des images <span class="pull-right"> Nombre d'images </span></b>
      </a>
      <a *ngFor="let item of countByDay | keyvalue | reverse" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        {{item.key | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} <span class="badge badge-pill bg-secondary pull-right">{{item.value}}</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The typescript part

```
  //Open the monthTracking div
  public openListDiv(id): void{
    let listMonths = document.getElementById("listMonths");
    let listCities = document.getElementById("listCities");
    if(id === "listMonths"){
      listMonths.style.display = "block";
      listCities.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
      listCities.style.display = "block";
      listMonths.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

The SCSS part

```
#listCities, #listDates, #listPms{
  display: none;
}

#listMonths, #listDates, #listCities, #listPms{
  width: 100%;
}

#colListDates{
  border: solid 1px red;
}

#colListMonth{
  border: solid 1px lawngreen;
}
```

Comment: The code and issue you mentioned is quite complicated to debug!! Can you tell me what you really want to do I mean any reference image. For example : this is a image and I want to make exactly or something like this. It will help us **(SO Community)** to better understand your problem.

Comment: @KunalTanwar Thank you very much for your quick response! What I really want is that when I click on the navigation bar (Grouping by month - Grouping by city), the div that we see on the 2nd image (number of images per day) stays on the right like in this image, instead of being below like in the 4th image. I hope my message is a little clearer ^^